# Probability predictions with model averaged Cumulative Link Mixed Models fitted with clmm in ordinal package

Tags: r, predict, mixed-models, ordinal

I found that the `predict` function is currently not implemented in cumulative link mixed models fitted using the `clmm` function in `ordinal` R package. While `predict` is implemented for `clmm2` in the same package, I chose to apply `clmm` instead because the later allows for more than one random effects. Further, I also fitted several `clmm` models and performed model averaging using `model.avg` function in `MuMIn` package. Ideally, I want to predict probabilities using the average model. However, while `MuMIn` supports `clmm` models, `predict` will also not work with the average model.

Is there a way to hack the `predict` function so that the function not only could predict probabilities from a `clmm` model, but also predict using model averaged coefficients from `clmm` (i.e. object of class "averaging")? For example:

```
require(ordinal)
require(MuMIn)

mm1 <- clmm(SURENESS ~ PROD + (1|RESP) + (1|RESP:PROD), data = soup,
        link = "probit", threshold = "equidistant")

## test random effect:
mm2 <- clmm(SURENESS ~ PROD + (1|RESP) + (1|RESP:PROD), data = soup,
        link = "logistic", threshold = "equidistant")

#create a model selection object
mm.sel<-model.sel(mm1,mm2)

##perform a model average
mm.avg<-model.avg(mm.sel)


#create new data and predict
new.data<-soup

##predict with indivindual model
predict(mm1, new.data)
```

I got the following error message:
 In UseMethod("predict") :
 no applicable method for `predict` applied to an object of class "clmm"

```
 ##predict with model average
 predict(mm.avg, new.data)
```

Another error is returned:
 Error in predict.averaging(mm.avg, new.data) : 
 `predict` for models 'mm1' and 'mm2' caused errors

Comment: Why isn't this question directed to the package authors? This seems extremely likely to be "too broad" in that it would require both theoretic and implementation exertion to do in a principled manner.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using clmm as well and yes I confirm predict.clmm is NOT (yet?) implemented. I didn't yet check the source code for fake.predict.clmm. It might work. If it doesn't, you're stuck with doing stuff by hand or using predict.clmm2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I found a potential solution (pasted below) but have not been able to make work for my data.

Solution here: https://gist.github.com/mainambui/c803aaf857e54a5c9089ea05f91473bc

I think the problem is the number of coefficients I am using but am not experienced enough to figure it out. Hopefully this helps someone out though.

This is the model and newdata that I am using, though it is actually a model averaged version. Same predictors though.

```
ma10 <- clmm(Location3 ~ Sex * Grass3 + Sex * Forb3 + (1|Tag_ID), data = 
IP_all_dunes)
ma_1 <- model.avg(ma10, ma8, ma5)##top 3 models
new_ma<- data.frame(Sex = c("m","f","m","f","m","f","m","f"),
                Grass3 = c("1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0"),
                Forb3 = c("0","0","1","1","0","0","1","1"))


# Arguments:
#  - model = a clmm model
#  - modelAvg = a clmm model average (object of class averaging)
#  - newdata = a dataframe of new data to apply the model to
# Returns a dataframe of predicted probabilities for each row and response level
fake.predict.clmm <- function(modelAvg, newdata) {
  # Actual prediction function
  pred <- function(eta, theta, cat = 1:(length(theta) + 1), inv.link = plogis) {
    Theta <- c(-1000, theta, 1000)
    sapply(cat, function(j) inv.link(Theta[j + 1] - eta) - inv.link(Theta[j] - 
eta))
  }

  # Multiply each row by the coefficients
  #coefs <- c(model$beta, unlist(model$ST))##turn off if a model average is used
  beta <- modelAvg$coefficients[2,3:12]
  coefs <- c(beta, unlist(modelAvg$ST))

  xbetas <- sweep(newdata, MARGIN=2, coefs, `*`)

  # Make predictions
  Theta<-modelAvg$coefficients[2,1:2]
  #pred.mat <- data.frame(pred(eta=rowSums(xbetas), theta=model$Theta))
  pred.mat <- data.frame(pred(eta=rowSums(xbetas), theta=Theta))
  #colnames(pred.mat) <- levels(model$model[,1])
  a<-attr(modelAvg, "modelList")
  colnames(pred.mat) <- levels(a[[1]]$model[,1])

  pred.mat
}
```